# Is it possible to use a capacitor and a resistor to keep voltage above 3v and limit current to a certain value?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-design

I have an RC helicopter and the electronics require a voltage of at least 3v. The electronics also have a certain max amperage which might be around 2 amps.

Under high load on the brushed motor, the voltage drops below 3v and the amperage rises dramatically.

Is it possible to add a capacitor and a resistor to keep voltage above 3v and limit current?

The voltage would not have to be kept above 3v for long, only 3 seconds at a time, for example.

I think what would work is 2 switches:

1. Opens when the voltage drops below 3V and connects the capacitor
2. Opens when the amperage goes above 2A and connects the resistor.

What switches meet these requirements?

Comment: If you limit current, then voltage goes down.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Keep voltage above 3v and limit current to below 2 amps.

Comment: In most cases, the current is dictated by the load not the voltage source, are you sure you are not confusing the fact that the battery might be rated at 2A max rather than having to limit the current to 2A?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: No, that's not going to work as the timescale is too long.  Besides, if your battery voltage is 3v, you need to land and recharge; deep discharge is not good for cell life.

Comment: @S.s. if the blade speed is regulated, and the motor driven by a switching ESC, then as the battery voltage goes down the current draw upon it would go up -- constant blade speed = constant power draw, constant power / reduced voltage = increased current.

Comment: `Under high load on the brushed motor, the voltage drops below 3v and the amperage rises dramatically.` ...  you have this backwards ... it sounds like you are saying that the current rises because of the lower voltage .... your statement should read `Under high load on the brushed motor, the current rises dramatically, which causes the voltage to drop below 3v.`

Answer (score 1):

Right now, it sounds like the battery voltage and the load voltage are one and the same. You can put a resistor between the battery and the load, and that will help keep the BATTERY voltage higher. But it will make the load voltage lower. Capacitor can't really help.

I also want to point out that there is a fundamental contradiction in what you are trying to do. You are trying to restrict the current to the load AND boost the load voltage. Those two things are opposites. Anything you do to restrict the current will make the load voltage sag even more.

It is like you have an employee who is sad and wants a raise. Then you tell him that you are cutting his pay and that also he must be happy. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: To be clear, the proposed resistor is a thought experiment; it won't help the actual situation in the slightest, only make things worse.

Comment: "it sounds like the battery voltage and the load voltage" - I think this is correct. The only things in the circuit are the motor and battery.

Comment: "I also want to point out that there is a fundamental contradiction in what you are trying to do." - I noticed this and I think one solution is to have 2 switches. I have updated the question.

Comment: @BSeven The switches don't help, so you can just leave them out.  However, you're going to have trouble getting a large enough capacitor for that idea to work.  A better idea would be to buy a better battery.  Again, strongly suggest describing what you actually want to do rather than asking how to do something that won't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitors are commonly used to supply extra current under a high load transient. Depending on how long the high load will be present, it might not be feasible to find capacitor(s) large enough... 3 seconds is probably way too long. If you don't need a TON more current, then you could put a resistor in series with the cap to increase the discharge time (you'll probably want to do that anyway, actually - just to keep the supply current more constant over that 3 second interval.) With the increased discharge time comes a decreased maximum current.

Some important equations to remember if you use a capacitor:

V_c = (V_i - V_f)*e^(-t/RC) + V_f

I_c = C*dV_c/dt

If the cap bank isn't going to do it, you can add an additional power supply just for the motor. If the power supply is governed by other circuitry, you could try tying a buffer IC to the input of the motor. The buffer will still need it's own power supply, but it's output voltage will follow whatever you tie it the input to, like that governing circuitry.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference -- Go thru this link to see how you can format the answer that contain math, more neatly.